# Loading local pictures throws 404 Not Found (AngularJS, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS (and JavaScript) and appreciate your indulgence.
I am struggling with loading local images into a grid-like structure, receiving Status Code 404 Not Found for the request "http://localhost:9000/{"url":"images/foopic.png"}".

The controller:

```
angular.module('FooApp')
    .controller('FooCtrl', function ($scope) {

        var pictures = $scope.pictures = [];

        var img = [{
            url: "images/foopic1.png"
        }, {
            url: "images/foopic2.png"
        }, {
            url: "images/foopic3.png"
        }, {
            url: "images/foopic4.png"
        }, {
            url: "images/foopic5.png"
        }, {
            url: "images/foopic6.png"
        }];

        var titles = ["Foo Pic1", "Foo Pic2", "Foo Pic3", "Foo Pic4", "Foo Pic5", "Foo Pic6"];

        var dummyText = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."];

        $scope.addPics = function (i) {
            pictures.push({
                title: titles[i],
                url: img[i],
                summary: dummyText[i]
            });
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.addPics(i);
        }

    });
```

The view:

```
<h1>Overfoo</h1>
<div class="thumbnails">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="pic in pictures">
        <img ng-src="{{pic.url}}">

        <h3>{{pic.title}}</h3>
        <p> {{pic.summary}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What do I have to change to load the pictures?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `url: img[i],` change this to `url: img[i].url,` or a better idea would be to change `var img` to an array of strings rather than objects

Comment: add '/' before your image url it might help

Comment: Thanks to George and Thennarasan for your super fast responses plus explanation - issue solved. Ahefaz: thx to you as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line right here

```
url: img[i]
```

You're setting the url on that object to be equal to another object and not a string because

```
img[i] == {url: "images/foopic1.png"}
```

So either change `url: img[i]` to be `url: img[i].url` **or** change your `img` array to be strings rather than objects, like so:

```
var img = ["images/foopic1.png", "images/foopic2.png", "images/foopic3.png", "images/foopic4.png", "images/foopic5.png", "images/foopic6.png"];
```

Personally I'd go with the option of changing the array to be strings as you're not storing any other information on the objects in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Its currently appending as "http://localhost:9000/{"url":"images/foopic.png"}".

Change the below

```
 $scope.addPics = function (i) {
        pictures.push({
            title: titles[i],
            url: img[i],
            summary: dummyText[i]
        });
    };
```

to

```
 $scope.addPics = function (i) {
        pictures.push({
            title: titles[i],
            url: img[i].url,
            summary: dummyText[i]
        });
    };
```

After modification it will append as "http://localhost:9000/images/foopic.png".